# Propagate gridview item checkable state to children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-gridview

I've a Gridview item defined as shown below, I've extended the RelativeLayout to make it checkable and this works fine.

Now I want also the ImageView (inside the RelativeLayout) receives the checkable state so I've extended it but the `setChecked` method is never called and the image never changes its style

I've tried to add to the ImageView the `duplicateParentState` set to `true` without success.

Maybe my approach is totally wrong, how can I change the ImageView style when the parent RelativeLayout is checked?

The grid_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.my.CheckableRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gridview_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.my.CheckableImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/place_holder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/caption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</com.my.CheckableRelativeLayout>
```

CheckableRelativeLayout

```
public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean isChecked;

    /** all ctors removed for simplicity */

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
        setSelected(isChecked);
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!isChecked);
    }
}
```

CheckableImageView

```
public class CheckableImageView extends ImageView implements Checkable {
    private boolean isChecked;

    /** all ctors removed for simplicity */

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
        setImageAlpha(isChecked ? 100 : 255);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!isChecked);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution myself thanks to this hidden (on the web) gem [post](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/)

The trick consists to call `setChecked` for all `Checkable` children, so I've simply added to the CheckableRelativeLayout the relevant code